# Correctly add string to a REG_BINARY type in Windows Registry

Tags: c++, windows, hash, registry, group-policy

I am trying to automate the process of adding software policy hash rules to Windows, and am currently having a problem adding valid hashes to the registry. This code creates a key and adds the hash to the registry:

```
HKEY* m_hKey;
string md5Digest;
string valueName = "ItemData";
vector<BYTE> itemData;

/*
use Crypto++ to get file hash
*/

//convert string to format that can be loaded into registry
for (int i = 1; i < md5Digest.length(); i += 2)
    itemData.push_back('0x' + md5Digest[i - 1] + md5Digest[i]);

// Total data size, in bytes
const DWORD dataSize = static_cast<DWORD>(itemData.size());

::RegSetValueEx(
    m_hKey,
    valueName.c_str(),
    0, // reserved
    REG_BINARY,
    &itemData[0],
    dataSize
);
```

This works fine, and adds the key to the registry:

[image: My hash rule]

But when comparing the registry key to a rule added by Group Policy you can see a very important difference:

[image: Windows added hash rule]

The 'ItemData' values are different between them. The bottom picture's ItemData value is the correct output. When debugging the program I can clearly see that md5Digest has the correct value, so the problem lies with the conversion of the md5Digest string to the ItemData vector of BYTEs or unsigned chars....

[image: Visual Studio Debugging]

What is the problem with my code, why is the data being entered incorrectly to the registry?

Comment: Looks like you are building the vector wrong since `char_code('x') + char_code('3') + char_code('D') = 0xEF` but you want 0x3D.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp How do I build the vector correctly then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string that you want to convert to a byte array. You can write a helper function to convert 2 chars to a BYTE:

```
using BYTE = unsigned char;

BYTE convert(char a, char b)
{
    // Convert hex char to byte
    // Needs fixin for lower case
    if (a >= '0' && a <= '9') a -= '0';
    else a -= 55;  // 55 = 'A' - 10
    if (b >= '0' && b <= '9') b -= '0';
    else b -= 55;

    return (a << 4) | b;
}
....
vector<BYTE> v;
string s = "3D65B8EBDD0E";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i+=2) {
    v.push_back(convert(s[i], s[i+1]));
}
```

v now contains `{0x3D, 0x65, 0xB8, 0xEB, 0xDD, 0x0E}`

Or, as mention by @RbMm, you can use the [`CryptStringToBinary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380285(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows function:

```
#include <wincrypt.h>
...
std::string s = "3D65B8EBDD0E";
DWORD hex_len = s.length() / 2;
BYTE *buffer = new BYTE[hex_len];
CryptStringToBinary(s.c_str(),
    s.length(),
    CRYPT_STRING_HEX,
    buffer, 
    &hex_len,
    NULL,
    NULL
    );
```

Comment: can do and this, or can use [CryptStringToBinaryW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380285(v=vs.85).aspx) with `CRYPT_STRING_HEX` flag

Comment: @RbMm Thanks. I was not aware of that function. I will update.

Comment: Marking as answer for concise code and for referencing WinAPI equivalent function.

Answer (score 1):

You have `'0x'` two-letter char literal summed up with `md5Digest[i - 1] + md5Digest[i]` and then trunketed to `BYTE`. This looked like you were trying to build "0xFF" byte value out of them. You should store md5 string directly:

```
const DWORD dataSize = static_cast<DWORD>(md5Digest.size());

::RegSetValueEx(
    m_hKey,
    valueName.c_str(),
    0, // reserved
    REG_BINARY,
    reinterpret_cast< BYTE const *>(md5Digest.data()),
    dataSize
);
```

If you actually need to store binary representation of hex numbers from md5 then you need to convert them to bytes like this:

```
BYTE char_to_halfbyte(char const c)
{
    if(('0' <= c) && (c <= '9'))
    {
        return(static_cast<BYTE>(c - `0`));
    }
    else
    {
        assert(('A' <= c) && (c <= 'F'));
        return(static_cast<BYTE>(10 + c - `A`));
    }
}

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < md5Digest.length(); i += 2)
{
    assert((i + 1) < md5Digest.length());
    itemData.push_back
    (
       (char_to_halfbyte(md5Digest[i    ]) << 4)
       |
       (char_to_halfbyte(md5Digest[i + 1])     )
    );
}
```

Comment: So should I remove the '0x' part?
(edit) Just tried and it produces something totally different than the above two examples

Comment: @AndrewLeFevre You can store it directly.

Comment: How would I store that directly?

Comment: Thanks for you're answer, but just tried this and it outputs again something different from the about examples and for some reason the output is twice as long.

Comment: @AndrewLeFevre Maybe you were trying to convert md5 hex numbers into bytes instead? e.g. so stored values would look like `3D 65` and so on?

Comment: Yeah I guess I was, sorry for not making that clearer. I didn't know that hex conversions were required but this did the trick! Thanks very much!